# Get index value from collection

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have an collection of strings: `"Apple", "Mange", "Pineapple"`

I want to get the index of the word having the longest length. For example, `2` which corresponds to the longest word, `"Pineapple"`.

Answer (score 3):

To get the fruit with the longest name, do this:

```
var fruits = new List<String> { "Apple", "Mange", "Pineapple" };
var longestName = (from fruit in fruits
                   orderby fruit.Length descending
                   select fruit).First();
var index = fruits.IndexOf(longestName);
```

And as a lambda, for no particular reason:

```
var fruits = new List<String> { "Apple", "Mange", "Pineapple" };
var longestName = fruits.OrderByDescending(e => e.Length).First();
var index = fruits.IndexOf(longestName);
```

Comment: Why does it need to be a lambda?

Answer (score 1):

The following could work too:

```
var maxItem = fruits
    .Select((fruit, index) => new { Length = fruit.Length, Index = index })
    .Aggregate((max, next) => (next.Length > max.Length) ? next : max);
var maxIndex = maxItem.Index;
```

Comment: +1 Although a little trickier to read IMHO, and I hope you don't mind my edit to get rid of those scrollbars.